# Width and Height is not applied to DIV tag

Tags: css, html, height, width

Hi,

I created a small popup with div of height and width 500px.Whenever I display it directly,It looks good.But When I put display:none by default and make it visible whenever I click the button,the popup is displayed with no height and width...Can anybody tel me the reason.....

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
         <head>
          <style>
           div{
             width:500px;
             height:500px;
             border:1px solid black;
             background:#988858;
             border-radius:14px;
             box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #666633;
             display:none;
           }
          </style>
         </head>

         <body>
          <button class="button">Click</button>

            <div id="Popup">
               <a href="#" id="Close" onClick="closePopup()">close</a>
            </div>

         </body>

         <script>
           document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0].addEventListener('click',showPopup,false);

           function showPopup(){
            //document.getElementById('Popup').style.width=500+'px';
            //document.getElementById('Popup').style.height=500+'px';
            document.getElementById('Popup').style.display='inline';
           }
           function closePopup(){
            document.getElementById('Popup').style.display='none';
           }

         </script>

        </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 document.getElementById('Popup').style.display='inline';
                                                  ^^^^
```

display inline does not support the height and width so use `block`

Answer (score 5):

Inline elements don't preserve width and height, you need to set the `display` to `block`.

Comment: The reason why it worked when you showed it directly is because Div tags default to "display:block;".

Answer (score 2):

`display:inline` doesn't support width and height. Try `display:block`.

Answer (score 1):

Can not use `initial` and `inline` properties of `display` here. `flex` and `inherit` are more suitable (alignment is same as when div loads for first time). apart from that you can use `inline-block`, `block` and `inline-flex`. Try flex :)